ionic 8 ion-content background image not shown properly with ion-header and ion-footer
I use ionic 8 with angular 18 and I want the header and footer to be transparent and show ion-content background-image in fullscreen mode, behind them.
I use the below code:
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title style="--opacity:1">
      Main
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="main ion-padding" [fullscreen]="true">
  <p></p>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-img slot="end" id="logo" src="/assets/images/logo.svg"></ion-img>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-note slot="end" color="light">
          title
     </ion-note>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center">
      <ion-button style="--opacity:1">submit</ion-button>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>

and in SCSS file:
ion-content.main {
    --background: url('/assets/images/landing.png') center/cover;
}

#logo {
    width: 25%;
}

but, it is not shown properly:



translucent property only work in the ios mode.
I would suggest to add a div and wrap the ion-content, ion-header and ion-footer in the div and add the background image on the div instead of adding it on the ion-content.
Then make the background of the ion-toolbar and ion-content as transparent using css.
<div class="ion-page">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title style="--opacity:1">
        Main
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content class="main ion-padding" [fullscreen]="true">
    <p></p>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-img slot="end" id="logo" src="/assets/images/logo.svg"></ion-img>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-note slot="end" color="light">
          title
       </ion-note>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center">
        <ion-button style="--opacity:1">submit</ion-button>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>
</div>

.ion-page {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300') center/cover;
}
.main, ion-toolbar {
  --background: transparent;
}

We can use ion-page in place of div but angular with ionic-8 does not support ion-page as component.

Thank you, it's working
in Ionic 8 Angular, the ion-page element does not exist instead I use ion-app.

There exist an ion-page component, its not listed in the components section of the doc but you can import and use it.

As ion-app is a component that should only be used once in the whole application.

In ionic8-angular, the template throw error is an unknown element when I use ion-page.

Updated the answer, I hope it helps.
